# Missing product attributes in Big Query Data Transfer from Merchant Center

Tags: google-bigquery

The Big Query Data Transfer from Google Merchant Center considers only a subset of the product attributes that are available via the Content API. For example, `customAttributes` or `size`, among others, are not included in the transfer.

For reference, I'm including links to the documentation pages that list available product attributes from both services:

- Attributes available via Content API: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2.1/products and https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2.1/productstatuses
- Attributes transferred to Big Query: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/merchant-center-transformation

**My question is**: is there any plan to include (at least some of) the missing attributes in a future release of the Merchant Center transfer?

Comment: Could you specify a list of the attributes you want to include?

Comment: We currently miss these attributes in particular: `sizes`, `sizeType`, `sizeSystem`, `warnings`, `promotionIds` and `customAttributes`. But, more generally, it would be great to have all product attributes available from BigQuery transfers in some way.